# can someone clarify rxjs observable import error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular 13 and rxjs 7.4.0. and vscode......when I do this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'. '/Applications/GenysisBuild/genysis-jta/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/rxjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rxjs';
```

Now this error has been popping up in prior versions with no clear solution.
There is also the option to do this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rx'
```

and install this: @types/rx

then the error goes away but I really have no idea what 'rx' is relative to "rxjs"

can someone please clarify this issue?....how do I get rid of this error using "rxjs"?

EDIT:
tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",      ....also tried 2015
    "module": "es2020",      ....also tried esnext
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,    ..with or without
    "esModuleInterop": true      ...with or without
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

also tried this:

```
 "typeRoots": [
 "node_modules/@types"
  ],
```

Comment: That's strange, it is trying to import from `dist/cjs/index.js` when it should be going to `src/index.ts` which points to `src/internal/Observable.ts`. Could you please try importing from `rxjs/index` and/or `rxjs/internal/Observable` and confirm these files are present in `node_modules/rxjs`? Most likely it's a configuration in your `tsconfig.json`. You can uninstall the `@types/rx` as the types are bundled with `rxjs`.

Comment: Try removing your `node_modules` directory and install everything from scratch.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton neither /index or /internal/Observable made a difference. I didn't see anything unusual in the tsconfig but I added it the question.

Comment: @martin .....Hey Martin.....this doesn't work either.

Comment: I still don't have an answer as to what cause this problem but upgrading vscode  to 1.65.2 seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the root cause, but after some experimentation I've found that adding in `tsconfig.json` the following lines seems to fix the issue on IntelliJ, with `"typescript": "~4.8.4"` and `"rxjs": "^7.8.0"` versions:

```
"target": "esnext",
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/operators/index.d.ts"
],
"paths": {
  "rxjs": ["./node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/index"]
}
```

Comment: Also in Intellij make sure you are using the correct Typescript version (bottom right menu), as with multiple ts modules in the project, it can pick a different version from the others modules.